# How can i optimize more my OpenCl kernel

Tags: opencl

I had separated out some functions which are different from one another but needs to run parallel in different workitems. Hence when kernel is called, it needs to decide which function has to be executed..

```
void call_calc0() {
    // code
}

void call_calc1() {
    // code
}

void call_calc2() {
    // code
}

void call_calc3() {
    // code 
}

__kernel void perform (__global double* A, __global double* B) {
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    if (idx == 0) {
        call_calc0();
    } else if (idx == 1) {
        call_calc1();
    } else if (idx == 2) {
        call_calc2();
    } else if (idx == 3) {
        call_calc3();
    }
}
```

If there are 256/512 workitems, this code sample will not be a correct way. How can i optimize this?

Comment: i could think of function pointers and preprocessor way.. but, is it possible to use function pointers in OpenCl?

Comment: Functions pointers are not allowed in OpenCL. Are you saying that every single work-item will have to execute completely different code?

Comment: yes. but on same buffer.. separate chunks of single buffer. is it possible.. I did some tests @jprice if i replace if-else with single "if" condition.. then compilation becomes very fast... code will be like if (idx == 1) {calc1}; if (idx == 2) {calc2}...

Comment: Sure, and you could achieve the same with a `switch` statement. However, the OpenCL NDRange execution model is designed for data-parallel execution, which is what devices such as GPUs and accelerators are great at. It sounds like your problem is not data-parallel at all (you are executing completely different code on the same data), which will potentially have very low performance for devices designed around SIMD execution. Are there really no common components in each of the different calculations you are performing?

Comment: in my model, there are will be 2 buffers and using them 3rd buffer will be updated. but equations might differ how they are using two buffer for making 3rd buffer for each element. hence very less is common.. but i am thinking i might get improvement for making 256/512 parallel faster threads which might result me in speedup... in my real test case.. i had found around 30-40%speed up..

Comment: You will probably be able *some* speed-up, but you won't be able to utilise the SIMD components of the device. You would probably be best of ensuring you have work-groups of size 1 to make sure the device doesn't try and pack work-items into SIMD lanes, which would result in a divergence nightmare.

Comment: yes, workgroups have the size of 1. you are correct. i tried ur suggestion of switch. benchmark of switch case didn't gave much speed up.. @jprice is there some way/workaround to call related functions?

Comment: If the logic is really as simple as you say and the local size is 1, why don't you just call 4 separate kernels and remove the conditional entirely? I agree with @jprice, this really doesn't sounds like a problem that maps well to OpenCL. Perhaps some more context would be useful.

Comment: 100% agreed with @jprice by saying this problem doesn't show SIMD.. It shows MISD either.. but i am trying to get parallel effect from opencl... @ TomFenech

Comment: @TomFenech if workgroup size is 512, then calling different 512 kernels?? will it not be an extra overhead..??

Comment: That depends entirely on a lot of the details that are currently missing from the question. At the moment it's too abstract to really provide any specific suggestions. In general, a kernel built entirely out of conditional statements with a workgroup size of 1 isn't the best fit for OpenCL.

Comment: thanks @TomFenech i will look into your suggestion as well as above comments. with new proper algorithm and way of solving will come back with proper question.. thanks again for your concern.. :)

Comment: Repeating what @jprice said: do NOT switch based on get_global_id(0)! It will be horrible for divergence and most of your GPU resources will be wasted. Your switching (and therefore divergence) should happen at a multiple of the warp/wavefront size (which could be 16 or 32).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best optimization, if possible would be to use four different kernels. You are calling this kernel with a group size of more than one, problems start to arise when it comes to execution in parallel.

If it is at all possible, try to separate your global memory or use it in very careful, non-colliding ways. This should allow you to create four separate kernels, and get rid of the conditional code execution.

When the first if/case is encountered, some of the work items of the group will run the code, but the other 75% of your work items will wait. Most opencl devices, especially GPUs, operate in this way. When those first 25% of work items are done, they will wait while the next if/case code is executed.

This applies to all branching in opencl, eg if/else, switch, for, and while/do. Whenever some of your work items in a group don't satisfy the condition, they wait for the others that do satisfy it. Then the 'else' group of work items executes while the 'if' group waits.

Another way to look at it is comparing CPU and GPU hardware. CPUs have a lot transistors dedicated to branch prediction and cache memory. GPUs are much more vector-base in nature, and are only recently beginning to support some of the more advanced flow-control features of CPUs.

Comment: This is the first rule of parallelizing in GPUs, as the first rule of OO programming. Putting everything in one single kernel/class, specially when the processes are completely uncorrelated, is a very bad approach. Sometimes the laziness of splitting the work in multiple kernels/classes, creates a headache problem in the future.

Comment: Yes, and without knowing what the functions being called actually do with the global memory, there's no telling for sure that it can be broken into separate kernels at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since OpenCL doesn't support function pointers, you are restricted to either `if/else` or `switch`. The performance of these two should be identical, it's just a difference in coding preference.

You could make things a little easier/cleaner with preprocessor macros. For example, you could do something like this:

```
#define CALL_CASE(i)    \
    case i:             \
        call_calc##i(); \
        break;          \

__kernel void perform (__global double* A, __global double* B) {
    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    switch (idx) {
        CALL_CASE(0);
        CALL_CASE(1);
        CALL_CASE(2);
        CALL_CASE(3);
        ... // etc
    }
}
```

If you are generating your `call_calcX()` functions automatically, it would be easy enough to also generate this `switch` block at the same time. If you are manually writing these `call_calcX()` functions, then it's only one extra line of code to add each function to the block. Not ideal, but not terrible either.

As per the comments above, this problem doesn't appear to be at all data-parallel, which will limit the ability to take advantage of the SIMD execution available in most OpenCL devices.

Comment: i totally agree with you for your SIMD comment. I need to think regarding the same.. As in my situation data is MISD.. let me think more for better algorithm. But as my question.. you gave me a solution.. Thanks for your concern.. :)